# Meaning of "whip into a lather"

Tags: idioms

> In New York, basketball phenom Jeremy Lin continues to **whip** fans of the Knicks **into a lather**.

What does *whip [somebody] into a lather* really mean?

Comment: It's from whipping a horse to make it gallop faster. Taken to extremes, the horse sweats so much it looks as if it's covered in soap lather. They can and do die from such treatment.

Comment: Why not make that an answer?  Why just a comment?

Comment: @thursdaysgeek: Perversely, in light of my position on [this meta question](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2440/), I think this is a reasonable question, but I couldn't easily find a good reference to back up what I know is the right answer. While someone else is finding that, I thought I might track down a movie I saw recently where the cowboys rode their horses so hard it looked like they'd been in a **bubble bath**! ... 50 secs later ... Gottit! - it's [Ride The High Country](http://sfy.ru/?script=ride_the_high_country_1962)

Comment: Ah, I understand.  And, in this case, I googled 'whip into a lather' and found a variety of meanings on the first page, including whipping a horse, but it was by no means the only and clear winner for a definition.  Yours is the correct answer, as far as I know.

Comment: But you could just whip anything in the kitchen up into a lather, don't you? Like, eggs, maybe? That seems closer to both plausibility and credibility.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's from whipping a horse to make it gallop faster. Taken to extremes, the horse sweats so much it looks as if it's covered in soap lather. They can and do die from such treatment. OP's context is slightly unusual - a more common form here would be [whip into a frenzy](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22snippet%20of%20information%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22whip%20into%20a%20frenzy%22&pbx=1&oq=%22whip%20into%20a%20frenzy%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=6039834l6039834l9l6040518l1l1l0l0l0l0l53l53l1l1l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=5a7d923adb37d5c0&biw=1359&bih=885) (the fans aren't being flogged to the point of exhaustion - they're becoming feverishly excited, like a crazed mob).

I recently saw what at first seemed ridiculous exaggeration in the movie [Bite the Bullet (1975)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0072705/). I thought the foam was way over the top, but my horse-riding sister told me it was credible (the movie involves a 700-mile "Endurance Race", so the horses would have been ridden pretty hard).

Thanks to @Hugo for pointing out that this somewhat unusual phenomenon occurs because horse-sweat is rich in [latherin](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19478940), a [surfactant](http://dermatology.about.com/od/glossarys/g/surfactant.htm) which encourages foaming. It can look extreme, but as [this comment on the movie](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00005YUNT) at amazon.com, says *"Hopefully there was a lot of soap lather being used."* I'll second that!

Comment: Search for *latherin* to find plenty of "veterinary-oriented" descriptions of horse sweat. [For example](http://www.horsetalk.co.nz/health/horsesweat-161.shtml): *Ever wondered why your horse lathers up when it sweats? It's all because of a special protein in the sweat appropriately named latherin.*

Answer (score 1):

Several dictionaries include a definition of *lather* that refers to horse sweat. For example, from [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lather):

> **1 a** : a foam or froth formed when a detergent (as soap) is agitated in water
>   **1 b** : foam or froth from profuse sweating (as on a horse)
>   **2**   : an agitated or overwrought state : dither (worked himself into a *lather*)

Here's an example from a 1793 [*Sporting Magazine*](http://books.google.fi/books?id=Y5saAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA349&dq=horse%20lather%20-leather%20whip&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wCRGT6-CC-HO4QSAhtizDg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=horse%20lather%20-leather%20whip&f=false):

> By no means be induced to countenance those *degrading flops* tea, coffee, or chocolate, but prove the strength of your stomach by the circumference of a *buttock of beef*, mollify the glans of the thorax with a jug of strong beer, and prevent any effervescent irritability by the friendly interposition of a *bumper* (or two) of brandy. Thus internally defended, you stand well prepared to " mount your fiery pegasus," then give the first proof of *your prudence* in setting out late, that you may enjoy the pleasure of riding hard *fifteen* or *twenty* miles, to bring your horse up to the company ***in a lather***, just as the hounds are going to throw off.

I also found several veterinary descriptions of horse sweat looking like a lather. Not only that, there's even a horse-sweat protein called *latherin*. For example from [*Equine exercise physiology*](http://books.google.fi/books?id=WnsvAQAAMAAJ&q=lather#search_anchor) by David Marlin and K. J. Nankervis:

> In addition to high levels of electrolytes, horse sweat contains a protein called latherin, which produces a lather on the skin. Latherin spreads sweat along the surface area over which sweat can evaporate. The latherin content of sweat seems to decrease during prolonged sweating.

Answer (score -5):

It is from whipping a human being into a frenzy, such as Roman slave or an African slave in Brazil or the US or Jesus prior to crucifixion or anyone -- 30 lashes, 100 lashes -- to the point that skin is literally whipped off and the pain and shock for the victim is so great that he is in a frenzied condition shrieking, screaming, sweating and bleeding, shaking, recoiling, vomiting, shitting, pissing.  If the ends of the whip contain metal shards, then it gets worse, cutting into the tissue and bone.

Humans often died from wicked, vicious whipping.  All this happy talk about horses and sweating and cowboys needs to pass and let us deal with the reality of human cruelty,  and the true historical nature of "being whipped into a frenzy, or 'lather,'" shall we?

Some empathy for the victims of whipping, including horses, would be nice.  And empathy such as Nietzsche showed when, coming upon a man viciously beating a donkey, he embraced the donkey, stopped the whipping and wept for the poor beast.  There is even a film about it.  Also, some empathy for the victims of US bombs which have been whipping humans into frenzies from seas to shining seas would also be nice.

Comment: What is your supporting evidence that the phrase originates from human whipping, not horsewhipping as other experts have claimed? Also, your second and third paragraphs do not seem to be either answer or evidence -- they seem more like a digression into the morality of whipping, rather than an answer to the question.